# 'NSString undeclared'

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

This is extremely silly, but I can't figure out how to use an NSString in my iPhone app musings.

I haven't imported anything special (just stdio.h). When I tried declaring:

```
NSString *test = @"Hello World"
```

and compiled, I get the error: `'NSString undeclared'`

How do I fix this? Also, when I try adding

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
```

I get 3951 build errors.

Comment: First see the you have Foundation framework in your projects

Comment: what do you mean by that and how would i do that?

Comment: I guess you aren't writing an Objective C program in `C++ stdc++` Application type. You should write your Objective C program in `Foundation` type of `Application`. See the image in my post.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`I haven't imported anything special (just stdio.h)`.

You should `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>`

You `Application` should be of type `Foundation`[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need to import `Foundation.h`.  You probably don't need or want `stdio.h`.

Comment: typo, back to the original question.

Comment: `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>`

Comment: just edited my answer to address that. adding that import causes 3951 build errors.

Comment: @hatorade, sounds like something else is going on - what are the first couple of those errors?

Comment: @hatorade, what are the errors? They should point you at what's going on.  How are you compiling/linking your program?  Do you have the Foundation framework in your include paths, for example?

Comment: here's what I did: I made a new xcode project, select Command Line Tool, and added the include statement above for Foundation. And I get all the build errors. It's literally just giving errors like `Expected identifier or `(` before '@' token` in NSObjCRuntime.h and other important files that I didn't write.

Comment: @hatorade, it sounds like you set up the wrong project type.  Check out @Mahesh's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
NSString *test=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello World"];
```

Cheers

Comment: The OP's code is fine (except for missing a semicolon) - if his problem is with not being able to find `NSString` at all, I'm pretty sure this suggestion isn't going to help him.

Answer (score 0):

This is also silly. Did you put a semicolon after the line?

Comment: yup (useless text so i can post the comment #THANKYOUSTACKOVERFLOW)